# Propagate changes from master to all the child branches

Tags: git

I'm working on a repo with multiple branches. The entire hierarchy of the repo is a big tree with several nodes. Few days ago in one of the branches I added some files which were pushed to parent branches(upto master) and other sibling and cousin branches pulled those changes into themselves. So now every branch has those files.

Today I want to remove those files from the repo so I removed them from master branch. Though my master branch does not have those files, all other child branches have them and I want to remove it from them as well. The linear approach would be to rebase every branch with its parent in a DFS/BFS manner. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Asking how to propagate changes in git makes me wonder if you know how git works. Remember branches in git aren’t always children of master. In my own repo master _has no “children”_.

Comment: I think you're right. I need to get my git concepts straight!

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt and not helpful. As you may already know a branch is a pointer to a commit, so to propagate those changes to a branch it must either be merged or rebased. This won’t propagate changes, but instead move the branch pointer, or commits and the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

All Child branches can pull from master (provided master does not have any changes the child branches should not have.)

Comment: Even this is a linear approach and would require checking out every branch.